# parsing tab delimited file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I can't change the server side, but I'm getting a file that looks like this:

```
0   20.59339    138402
1   11.20062    75276
2   32.07597    215573
3   12.2029 82012
4   6.800035    45701
5   0.6548425   4401
6   0.8643445   5809
7   0.7174848   4822
8   0.813457    5467
9   0.7198655   4838
10  0.8152425   5479
11  1.396878    9388
12  1.93953 13035
13  4.410404    29641
14  1.392266    9357
15  0.7592959   5103
16  1.040368    6992
17  1.603107    10774
```

I have Liquid, javascript, and jquery at my disposal.  From Liquid, I shoved the contents into a div with no style, hoping that I could parse the file somehow.  But when I looked at it in Firebug, I just see my div with the contents as one giant string (at least that's what it looks like).

Edit: I need to do some math on the data.

Comment: split data at line breaks for array of lines, not sure what expected output should be though. If you just want what's shown, put data in a `<pre>` tag without any parsing needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but if you need to do calculations on the numbers in the data, then you could try something like this:

```
var data;
$.get('data.txt', function(d){
    data = d;
});
```

Then split that data first, based on newlines:

```
data = data.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Then you can split based on whitespace, and you'll have a reasonable way to look at the data:

```
var lines = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    lines.push(data[i].split(/[ ]+/));
}
```

Of course, this is a really simple break down... You probably want to change that last part for a bit more ease of access. But, you could just write a function to read a line and manipulate the data accordingly, where

`line[0][0]` - the index, or line number and first column

`line[0][1]` - the second column

`line[0][2]` - third column

ex:

```
>lines[4]
>["4", "6.800035", "45701"]
```

Comment: can you explain what the lines.push(data[i].split(/[ ,]+/)); does?  It works great, but being a regex noob, I don't see what is happening.

Comment: I apologize, I had a slight brain fart. The comma is totally unnecessary. I'm going to fix it now.

But, /[ ]+/ will just match space characters between one and unlimited times.

String.prototype.split() takes a separator (the regex in this example) and matches it against the whole string.

So for each line (string), you split it into an array based on whitespace.