# Nodejs - Writing a tab delimited file as json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

Is there a npm module which converts a tab delimited file to a JSON object so i could look up the data by certain properties.

Example: The file would looks like below,

```
name sex age
A    M   20
B    F   30
C    M   40
D    F   50
```

JSON

```json
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "sex": "M",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "sex": "F",
    "age": "30"
  },
  /* Etc. */
]
```

Comment: Show us an example of the file, please. As well as the expected output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27495879/1814524

Answer (score 5):

*Sometimes i prefer not using node modules so that I can run these scripts without any setup....*

*IE. nodejs ./convert-to-csv.js*

Here is a nodejs script in case you choose not to use a node module.

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./birthrate_poverty.txt","utf8", function(err, data){
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    var json = [];
    var keys = [];

    rows.forEach((value, index)=>{
        if(index < 1){// get the keys from the first row in the tab space file
            keys = value.split("\t");
        }else {// put the values from the following rows into object literals
            values = value.split("\t");
            json[index-1] = values.map((value, index) => {
                return {
                    [keys[index]]: value
                }
            }).reduce((currentValue, previousValue) => {
                return {
                    ...currentValue,
                    ...previousValue
                }
            });
        }
    })


    // convert array of objects into json str, and then write it back out to a file
    let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
    fs.writeFileSync("./birthrate_poverty.json", jsonStr, {encoding: "utf8"})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, csvtojson and the delimiter can be anything not only commas.
Example:

```
const csvFilePath='FILE'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv({delimiter:"\t"})
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
  console.log(jsonObj);
 })
 .on('done',(error)=>{
  console.log('end');
})
```